# Bug using conda command via ansible

Tags: python, ansible, conda, rhel7, miniconda

I'm trying to automate a Miniconda install via ansible role.
I didn't paste the whole error as I'm trying to understand those permission error, hoping that it is the real problem, I don't get why *conda* tries to create files or folders with path */.cph_xxx*.
If anyone already had this problem, I'd really like to know.
My work is a bit complicated to describe, I'm testing an ansible role with molecule. So all this code is executed in a RHEL7 Docker Container.

Here is my tasks/main.yml file in the role :

```
---
# necessary steps to deploy the role.
- name: 'Add the user {{ miniconda_user }} with a bash shell'
  user:
    name: '{{ miniconda_user }}'
    shell: /bin/bash

- name: check if already installed
  stat: path={{ miniconda_home }}/bin/conda
  register: bin_conda
  changed_when: bin_conda.stat.exists == False
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ miniconda_user }}'

- name: Create a tmp directory if it does not exist
  file:
    path: '{{ miniconda_tmp }}'
    state: directory
    mode: '0755'
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ miniconda_user }}'

- name: download miniconda installer
  get_url:
    url={{ miniconda_url }}
    dest={{ miniconda_tmp }}/miniconda.sh
    mode=0755
  register: miniconda_downloaded
  when: bin_conda.stat.exists == False
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ miniconda_user }}'

- name: install miniconda
  shell: '{{ miniconda_tmp }}/miniconda.sh -b -f -p {{ miniconda_home }}'
  register: miniconda_installed
  when: miniconda_downloaded | success
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ miniconda_user }}'

- name: remove miniconda setup script
  file: name={{ miniconda_tmp }}/miniconda.sh state=absent
  when: miniconda_installed | success
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ miniconda_user }}'

- name: Recursively change ownership of Miniconda a directory
  file:
    path: '{{ miniconda_home }}'
    state: directory
    recurse: yes
    mode: '0755'
    owner: '{{ miniconda_user }}'
    group: '{{ miniconda_user }}'

- name: update miniconda
  shell: '{{ miniconda_conda_bin }} update --all'
  register: miniconda_installed
  when: miniconda_downloaded | success
  become: yes
  become_user: '{{ miniconda_user }}'
```

What I don't get is that the last step, `conda update` gives me the following error, despite every step before works :

```
fatal: [instance]: FAILED! => {
  "changed": true, 
  "cmd": "/home/proxirhmanager/miniconda/bin/conda update --all", 
  "delta": "0:00:08.547853", "end": "2019-10-01 09:14:57.246143", 
  "msg": "non-zero return code", 
  "rc": 1, 
  "start": "2019-10-01 09:14:48.698290", 
  "stderr": "
  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.cph_tmp05aumjox'
  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.cph_tmp4au09jia'
  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.cph_tmp33mgqg0y'
  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.cph_tmpo10r_iv1'
  [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.cph_tmpnbwz5bvs'
  "
```

Comment: have you tried to execute that manually with the same user?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I just did on a "normal" Ubuntu system. It appears that miniconda install works perfectly fine but it leaves empty folders called .cph_xxx at the root of the miniconda folder.

Comment: I'm not sure but this problem may be related to the fact that one single file, like .bashrc in the home of the user, does not have the right permissions. It's just a hint, not a certain solution

Comment: `.bashrc` is mostly used for setting the user specific variables that gets loaded automatically when the user logs in. Is the error from ansible in debug mode ? i.e. executed with `-vvvv`?

Comment: Hi, no this message was not in vvv mode.

Comment: If this is still an issue for you please update the question with ansible debug output using `-vvvv` with the ansible command line.

Comment: have you solved this? thnx